# Access writing violation location in c

Tags: c

Access writing violation in a function that is intended to take names and information of employees. When I open the function via a switch it asks for the name of the employee but when I press enter I get the error code.

> Unhandled exception at 0x6559DBE9 (msvcr120d.dll) in Assignment4.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x009A6858.

The code that I believe to be the cause

```
typedef struct person
{
    char emplyName[5][SIZE];
    float emplyHours[5];
    float emplyRate[5];
    float emplyGross[5];
    float emplyBase[5];
    float emplyOvrt[5];
    float emplyTax[5];
    float emplyNet[5];
    float emplyTotal[5];
}input;
void menu(void);

void editEmployees(input* emply);

void print(input* emply);

void employeeInfo(input* emply);

int main(void)
{
    struct person *payroll={""};
    int choice = 0;
    menu();
    scanf_s("%c", &choice,1);
    switch (choice){
    case '1':{
        employeeInfo(payroll);
        break;
    }
    case '2':{
        editEmployees(payroll);
        break;
    }
    case '3':{
        print(payroll);
        break;
    }
    case '4':{
        break;
    }
    default:
        printf("Invalid entry\n");
    }
    system("pause");
}




void employeeInfo(input *emply)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
        printf("Enter employee name.\n");
        scanf_s("%s", &emply->emplyName[i]);
        printf("Enter employee hours.\n");
        scanf_s("%f", &emply->emplyHours[i]);
        printf("Enter Hourly rate.\n");
        scanf_s("%f", &emply->emplyRate[i]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: `%s` does not usually need an ampersand: `scanf_s("%s", emply->emplyName[i]);`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight not sure if that's true, but it does not solve my problem....

Comment: isn;t it like `%s` needs two parameters with `scanf_s()`?

Comment: Why do you have only one item for the name (a char array) but *five* for all of each persons' parameters?

Comment: That was a typo...it should read char emplyName[5][SIZE];

Comment: That data structure is designed terribly anyway.  You should keep the information about *one* employee in a `struct person` and then use an array of `person`s.

Comment: @5gon12eder: ... right. It will make the very first ampersand comment relevant as well. The problem lies in the arrays.

Comment: @5gon12eder I don't know what you mean exactly..But I'm thinking something like  `typedef stuct person[ ] {                                                        char emplyName;
    float emplyHours;
    float emplyRate;
    float emplyGross;
    float emplyBase;
    float emplyOvrt;
    float emplyTax;
    float emplyNet;
    float emplyTotal;}

Comment: `struct person { char name[SIZE]; float hours; … };` to declare the `struct` and then `struct person employees[5];` to get an array of 5 of them.

Comment: @5gon12eder that maneuver created about 19 errors in the rest of my code

Comment: You cannot expect anybody to refactor your homework in the comments under a SO question.  We can only give you some hints.  Yes, changing your data structures requires you to change the code that uses them as well or you'll get plenty of errors.

Comment: @5gon12eder will this approach prevent the access violation??? Not asking you to "refactor" my homework nor am I asking for a hint... Just need a clear reason why the code is not working.

Comment: The code is not working for the reasons dasblinkenlight and Sourav Ghosh mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The *emply pointer could be invalid. It could be null or point to random location.

Answer (score -2):

Try this.  It's not a complete answer as you do need to use a reference to retrieve the values, but it will get you moving

```
void employeeInfo(input emply)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
        printf("Enter employee name.\n");
        scanf_s("%s", emply.emplyName[i]);
        printf("Enter employee hours.\n");
        scanf_s("%f", emply.emplyHours[i]);
        printf("Enter Hourly rate.\n");
        scanf_s("%f", emply.emplyRate[i]);
    } 
}
```